# RANKX excluding users registered less then 3 months ago

Tags: powerbi, dax, rank

I want to calculate the users rating using this formula :

```
«users rating» = «sales rank» * 0.75 + «bonus rank» * 0.25
```

«sales rank» and  «bonus rank» — ranging sales growth in % (last month to a month before that (2 months ago)

Its August now so we need to calculate % growth June/July.

User is included to this calculation if he's been registered more then 3 months ago (current month excluded).

Our model contains the following tables :

```
Users
user_id
name 
registration_date
```

and :

```
Sales
month_code – year and month in YYYYMM format
user_id 
sale  
bonus
```

Need to make a table like this:

```
User    Sales   Bonus   Average rating
Name    1000000 2000000 1,3
```

I tried the following :

rank bonus =  RANKX(ALLSELECTED(Dim_manager), CALCULATE( [growth bonus]))

Answer (score 0):

I will assume that today's date is 2023-08-01. So, registered more than 3 months ago means anyone registered before 2023-05-01:

```
EligibleUsers = 
FILTER(
    Users,
    Users[registration_date] < DATE(2023, 5, 1)
)
```

You need to calculate sales growth and bonus growth for each user:

```
SalesGrowth = 
VAR JuneSales = CALCULATE(SUM(Sales[sale]), Sales[month_code] = 202306)
VAR JulySales = CALCULATE(SUM(Sales[sale]), Sales[month_code] = 202307)
RETURN
DIVIDE(JulySales - JuneSales, JuneSales)

BonusGrowth = 
VAR JuneBonus = CALCULATE(SUM(Sales[bonus]), Sales[month_code] = 202306)
VAR JulyBonus = CALCULATE(SUM(Sales[bonus]), Sales[month_code] = 202307)
RETURN
DIVIDE(JulyBonus - JuneBonus, JuneBonus)
```

Then using the RANKX function to be able to rank users:

```
SalesRank = 
RANKX(ALLSELECTED(EligibleUsers), [SalesGrowth])

BonusRank = 
RANKX(ALLSELECTED(EligibleUsers), [BonusGrowth])
```

Then :

```
UserRating = 
[SalesRank] * 0.75 + [BonusRank] * 0.25
```

Your final table :

```
MyTable = 
ADDCOLUMNS(
    EligibleUsers,
    "Sales", CALCULATE(SUM(Sales[sale]), Sales[month_code] = 202307),
    "Bonus", CALCULATE(SUM(Sales[bonus]), Sales[month_code] = 202307),
    "Average Rating", [UserRating]
)
```

Comment: @Brooly if the answer responds to your need please validate it

Comment: use TODAY() if you want to compare to a dynamic current date value. (and not DATE(yyyy,mm,dd)